# How to join all values of a specific attribute in a list?

Tags: java

I'd like to join all `String name` attributes of a list, separated by a slash `/`. Especially it's important that eg. the last entry does not get a slash appended at the end.

```
List<MyClass> list;

class MyClass {
   String name;
}
```

What is the best way doing this (I cannot use Java 8). Is there any library, eg `Guava`, that provides this functionality out of the box, and that I maybe havn't found yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guava provides a [`Lists.transform`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) method that lets you extract all `name` attributes into a list, like this:

```
List<String> names = Lists.transform(list, new Function<MyClass,String>() {
    public String apply(MyClass obj) {
        return obj.name;
    }
});
```

It also provides a [string `Joiner`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Joiner), which lets you complete the task:

```
String namesSeparatedBySlash = Joiner.on("/").join(names);
```

Of course you could put a call to `Lists.transform` inside the call of `join` to do it in a single statement, like this:

```
String namesSeparatedBySlash = Joiner
    .on("/")
    .join(
         Lists.transform(list, new Function<MyClass,String>() {
            public String apply(MyClass obj) {
                return obj.name;
            }
        })
    );
```